# Overcast Podcast App: How to Play from Oldest to Newest?

Tags: ios

With the Overcast podcast app (from Marco Arment), is there a way to play episodes within a single podcast from oldest to newest?  The default iOS podcast app does this, but I prefer the other features of Overcast.  I just don't see any way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for this also and stumbled on a solution. In the podcast playlist, tap on the UNPLAYED or ALL toggle to reverse the sort order of the feed. So you would tap it once to sort episodes from oldest to newest, then episodes will play from the top of the feed i.e. Oldest to newest

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of today - Overcast users can create a new Playlist and include any (or all) podcasts. Within this new playlist they can sort and prioritize as they want. It took me less than a minute to set this up, after I did 30 minutes of research online. Am posting here in the hope to reduce the search time for others.

Comment: This requires every single podcast to be manually added to the playlist, including every new one you subscribe to. A workaround, but not a great solution. I'm disappointed in this still not being a feature in Overcast almost 7 years later.